# Overlap frames in short term fourier transform

Tags: stft

I'm trying to understand the aim of overlapping frames in the short term fourier transform. Why is it important to do it? I have been told that it's to avoid "problems" at the frontiers of frames. But does anyone have a more precise or mathematical explanation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: bigger frames have more frequency resolution but less time resolution. In a really big frame you would know exactly what frequencies were present but not what time. The solution is to use overlapping frames to get more frequency resolution and still know what time those frequencies were present.

Comment: I don't understand why frequency resolution depends on that. I thought frequency resolution was depending on the duration of the observation: here the duration of the frame.